# Horizontal Table: ! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I wish to plot an horizontal table. When I run the code I got the following error message *"! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders`. If I move the line `\caption{Test Table}\label{tab:label_test}` below `\end{adjustbox}` I can run the compiler but the Table caption is vertical (not horizontal )

```
   \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.5\textwidth, angle=90}
    \begin{tabular}{ l | c c | c c | c c | c c | c c}
    \hline\hline
          \textbf{Algoritmo} 
        & \textbf{NSL-KD}         
        & \textbf{CTU-13}         
        & \textbf{UNSW-NB15}      
        & \textbf{UGR16}          
        & \textbf{AndMall7}       
        & \textbf{CICIDS17}       
        & \textbf{CIDDS-001}      
        & \textbf{Netflow-IDS}    
        & \textbf{NGIDS-DS}       
        & \textbf{CICIDS18} \\ \hline      
    One-Class SVM      &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ 
    Isolation Forest   &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ \hline
    K-NN               &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ 
    ODIN               & 62.65 &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       & 33.33 \\ \hline
    SDO                &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ 
    LOF                &       &       &       &       &      &       &       & 92.50 &       & 33.33 \\ 
    COF                &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       & 33.33 \\ \hline
    K-Means            &       &       & 71.44 &       &      &       &       &       & 92.89 &       \\ 
    DBSCAN             &       &       &       & 32.83 &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ 
    LDCOF              &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ \hline
    FastADOB           &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       & 33.33 \\ \hline
    HBOS               &       &       &       &       & 1.62 & 82.95 &       &       &       &       \\ 
    SOS                &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ 
    ISOS               &       &       &       &       &      &       &       &       &       &       \\ \hline
    SOM                &       & 11.25 &       &       &      &       & 89.62 &       &       &       \\ \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}    
    \caption{Test Table}\label{tab:label_test}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: adjustbox is like `\scalebox` or `\mbox`  so just has a single line and can not have display material like a caption. Perhaps you want `sidewaystable` from the rotating package? (scaling tables should be avoided if at all possible)

Comment: Thanks. I am using a template from the University (a very bad template). I can not use sidewaystable. Is there a way to rotate the caption?

Comment: you could use a `\parbox` inside the adjustbox.